# Swift ui AppStorage with ForEach Widget not working as expected

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a piece of code that saves an array of object

```
struct Profile: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var title: String = ""
}
```

implemented in view as

```
@AppStorage("profilesString") var profiles = [Profile]()
```

then I wanted to use this profiles in a Grid

```
Grid(alignment: .center, verticalSpacing: 32){
    ForEach(profiles, id: \.self) { p in
        GridRow{
            TextField(
                "Required",
                text: Binding(
                    get: { p.title },
                    set: { newTitle in
                        if !newTitle.isEmpty,
                           let index = profiles.firstIndex(of: p){
                        profiles[index].title = newTitle
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
}
```

This works perfectly but when used inside ForEach it only allows to put a character at a time, then loses focus. I think that it updates the title, then the profiles make update the ForEach and its rebuild make me lose focus.
This happens also if I use a ColorPicker with a color into the struct

I do not want lose focus when editing and save in place

Comment: you can try this little code, using the exactly TextField inside and outside of the ForEach and you will see that outside this works as expected

Comment: After some trying i can confirm that the problem is the ForEach, as the same problem happens with VStack and HStack instead of Grid and GridRow

Comment: This also goes wrong with List(profiles)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, where you update the `Profile` to be `Identifiable`,
and use bindings in the `ForEach`, as shown in the example code. This is
considered more robust than using the unsafe index into an array.

Note, `@AppStorage` is not the appropriate place to store an array of `[Profile]`.

```
struct Profile: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable { // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("profiles") var profiles:[Profile] = [Profile]()
    
    // for testing
 //   @State var profiles = [Profile(title: "title-1"), Profile(title: "title-2"), Profile(title: "title-3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        Grid(alignment: .center, verticalSpacing: 32) {
            ForEach($profiles) { $p in  // <--- here, $
                GridRow{
                    TextField("Required", text: $p.title)  // <--- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the appropriate place?

Comment: The problem with this is that you lose focus for each character you write, so i cannot use this type of foreach and i have to use the indexed one. But the binding thing will be usefull for another time

Comment: In a SwiftUI app to store more data than simple settings,  
you could have a look at [SwiftData](https://developers.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/)  and 
[Adopting SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/adopting_swiftdata_for_a_core_data_app). Re the problem, 
  `...lose focus for each character you write`, I don't see this with my code, tested on MacOS 14 using Xcode 15.
Maybe you have some other code (that you are not showing) interfering with TextField. All works well for me in my tests.

Comment: I'm using xcode 14.3.1 and MacOS 13.5, tried with an empty view and the result is the same. also i changed the AppStorage name but the behaviour is the same, i think that this might be a macos bug fixed on newer versions

Comment: Cannot use Swift Data as my app is targeting MacOS 13

Comment: for MacOS 13, there is [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) which is what `SwiftData` is build on.

Answer (score 0):

Find the problem, the fact is that ForEach is made for static values and so it does not work well with this binding, my workaround is create

```
ForEach(0..<profiles.count, id: \.self){ index in
TextField("Insert", text: $profiles[index].title)
}
```

this also gives a better readability of the code and I suggest this in every case of ForEach needs to modify a value

Comment: This is considered unsafe. You can watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: Are you talking about the identity needing?

Comment: Ranges, the use of an index, the use of self.

Comment: I really want to use the value itself, but swift ui make lose focus to textfield after each character if I use the value directly or a binding of it as suggested, so it is unusable, at least on macos, maybe this work on ios/ipados. As say it is a workaround